# Xamarin forms: ListView Item not firing for the second time in UWP

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

When I select an item in the listview for the second time it is not firing. I am using the **ItemSelected** property of the listview.

I research about this and found the solution like **setting a null value for the selected item at the end of the code, like below:

```
 ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
```

I am calling a displayactionsheet when tapping on a listview item.** When I set null at the end, the **displayactionsheet showing  2 times** in the android but working perfectly in uwp section.

Also, try **ItemTapped** property of listview with a null value at the end. **Which is working perfectly in android and breaking the app in UWP.** I don't have mac access now, so don't know what will happen at the IOS side.

Is there any solution for this? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this issue by setting null value, but not in the code of question, like below:

```
Mylocationslist.SelectedItem = null;
```

Mylocationslist is my listview name.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like implementing behaviors on your `ListView` would solve your issue. 
check out this [Xamarin Blog Post](https://blog.xamarin.com/turn-events-into-commands-with-behaviors/) for a tutorial.